# Load converted List<String> into listview

Tags: android, list, listview

I have a filled List (ServicesList) - of type String, custom class (ServiceRecord.java), custom adapter() and a custom listview (lvS) in my android application.

I have been able to convert the List variable to a Custom  List through the following code:

```
    List<ServiceRecord> objectList = (List)servicesList;
    ServicesCustomAdapter adapter = new ServicesCustomAdapter(this, objectList);
    lvS.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to set the converted list into the listview but I am getting an error 'java.lang.classexception: java.lang.String cannot be cast to app.services.net.ServiceRecord'. Can someone PLEASE show me how I can go about it.

My Custom class is as follows:

```
public class ServiceRecord {
    private String service;


    public String getService() {
        return service;
    }
    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

}
```

And my Custom adapter:

```
public class ServicesCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ServiceRecord>{
    private List<ServiceRecord> items;

    public ServicesCustomAdapter(Context context, List<ServiceRecord> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_service, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_service, null);            
        }

        ServiceRecord bbs = items.get(position);

        if(bbs != null) {
            //TextView un = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
            TextView tvservice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvservice);


            if(tvservice != null) tvservice.setText(bbs.getService());

        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Error is self explanatory . Object types not matches during downcasting .

Comment: How can I solve this? Please show me how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `List` which contain `ServiceRecord` class objects. Try the code below .

```
 List<ServiceRecord> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String item: servicesList){
        ServiceRecord sr=new ServiceRecord();
        sr.setService(item);
        objectList.add(sr);
    }
    ServicesCustomAdapter adapter = new ServicesCustomAdapter(this, objectList);
    lvS.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**PS:** While your `ServiceRecord` class has only one property . So why not just use a `List<String>` to accomplish the list adapter.

Comment: So, size of `objectList` = 0?

Comment: FYI, I'm going to add more properties in the ServiceRecord class. That's why it need this approach. Thank you very much my friend

Comment: Yeah thats what i though. Thx .